# Smarty, use template functions from included template

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have a Smarty (version 3.1.21) template like this:

```
<div>
    {include file='includes/test.tpl'}
    {pagebuilder data=$data.top_description}
</div>
```

`includes/test.tpl` content is:

```
{function name=pagebuilder}
    {foreach $data as $row}
       ...
    {/foreach}
{/function}
```

Error message is:

> Syntax error in template
>   "/home/master/projet/public/templates/controllers/pagebuilder-preview.tpl"
>   on line 29 "{pagebuilder data=$data.Content}" unknown tag
>   "pagebuilder"

How to ommit `unknown tag` error after include file and properly use function from included template?

Answer (score 2):

External defined template functions must be called with the `{call}` tag.
So your base template should be rewrited into:

```
<div>
    {include file='includes/test.tpl'}
    # {pagebuilder data=$data.top_description} 
    {call name=pagebuilder data=$data.top_description}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using assign:

```
{include file='includes/test.tpl' assign=pagebuilder}
```

Comment: Thanks but same issue :(